# Implementation Logic for a Chip UI with Expand/More functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

I need to implement a functionality where there is an autocomplete and after selecting an option the selection is displayed in the format of a chip beneath the autocomplete.There can be a **maximum of 10 chips/selections**.

I was able to figure out this functionality for tablet and larger screens.

**UI on larger Screens**
[image: UI on larger Screens]

The problem is with screens that are smaller in size.
On mobile screens i need to show +(count)more after displaying all the chips that can fit in the availble viewport space.
Examplary implementation :

- **2 small Chips that can fit and more button** [image: 2 small Chips that can fit and more button]
- **Chip with longer string and more button** [image: Chip with longer string and more button]

On clicking +more a pane should open in the bottom of the screen as below

**Bottom Pane on more click** [image: Bottom Pane on more click]

The above mentioned UI is from an android applicatoin and I am trying to implement the same using HTML, CSS.

**I need to implement this without a 3rd party npm package/ ui library like material ui.**

I tried applying flex and overlfow hidden properties on the parent div which contain the chip div's but the ending div gets cropped.